# VLOOKUP style query with wildcards in range portion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on an automatic tagging project and was wondering if there was a way to search for the first instance of a string contained within the search string:

#### Tag Table

| name contains | tag to apply |
| --- | --- |
| A/C | HVAC |
| Air Conditioner | HVAC |
| Lights | Lighting |
| Elevator | Elevator |
| ... |  |

#### Name table

| name | inferred tag |
| --- | --- |
| A/C 1 | HVAC |
| A/C 2 | HVAC |
| Elevator 4 | Elevator |
| Elevator 4 Lights | Lighting |
| ... |  |

basically I want the inferred tag to be `tag to apply` the first time `name` contains an item in `name contains`

VLOOKUP almost works but it only supports wildcards in the search item but not the range portion
so I can't apply *&<name_contains>&* wildcards to the Tag Table and do VLOOKUP that way unfortunately

I've done something similar in the past with scripts but I was hoping there was a way to do it with regular functions

One thing I though of doing is transposing the Tag Table and doing a see if each tag table name contains is in the name table name but the sizes of each table caused the sheet to reach the max allowed cells (~40000 names and ~280 tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(D1:D, 
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>""))), 
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B1:B&"×", B1:B<>"")), )),,9^9))), "×")),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this really seems to be along the right lines, I tested adding LOWER to D1:D and A1:A to make it case insensitive and that worked. It seems to have trouble dealing with tens of thousands of rows but I am able to work with this. By The Way what does the Query(,,9^9) part of the equation do?

Comment: @EricBlum it merges all columns into one single column (coz each item from A column gets distributed into separate column by TRANSPOSE). 9^9 means "all possible rows" tho it could be any number greater than total rows of the sheet

Comment: some real excel magic. It works for 27000 cols i got when I removed duplicate names